# Grails: local tests pass, Test environment tests fail

Tags: testing, grails

I have a Grails application that, when run on my local Windows machine, passes all tests in my integration test suite. When I deploy my app to my Test environment in Jenkins, and run the same suite of tests, a few of them are failing for inexplicable reasons.

I think the Test box is Linux but I am not sure. I am using mocks in my Grails app and am wondering if that may be causing confusion in values returned.

Has anyone any ideas?

EDIT:
My app translates an XML document into a new XML document. One of the elements in the returned XML document is supposed to be PRODUCT but comes back as product.

The place where this element is set is from an in-memory database that is populated from a DB script. It is the same DB script that is used locally and on my Test environment.

The app does not read any config files that would be different in different environments.

Comment: Not enough informations are provided. Please tell us exactly which kind of test passes and fails and in which situations. Tell us about the environnement where tests were made.

Comment: Do you have any reference to the system in your tests? such as reading a file in your tests? As Matt mentioned you need to add more information. For example, the error that you are getting on the test box.

Comment: I had some troubles with break lines difference, but as Matt said, there isn't enough info to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have stated the really isn't enough information here to help give a solid answer.  A couple of things that I would look at are:

1. If it's integration tests that are failing maybe you've got some "bad tests" that are dependent on certain data that does not exist in your test environment that Jenkins is running against.
2. There is no guaranteed consistency for test execution order across machines/platforms.  So it's entirely possible that the tests pass for you locally just because they run in a certain order and leave things mocked out or data setup from one test that is needed in another.  I wrote a plugin a while ago (http://grails.org/plugin/random-test-order) to help identify these problems.  I haven't updated the plugin since Grails 1.3.7 so it may not work with 2.0+ grails apps.
3. If the steps above don't identify the problem knowing any differences in how you are invoking the tests on Jenkins vs. Local would be beneficial.  For example if you specify a specific grails environment (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments) when running on Jenkins and what the differences are between that and the grails environment used on your local.

Comment: I run the tests on Test as follows: "clean --non-interactive"  "test-app -unit -integration  --non-interactive". When I run the tests locally with the same command, they all pass.

Comment: I am going to try your plugin. I suspect that it could be the issue. I was wondering was there such a plugin available. Good work from you.